# Flutter package duplicate symbols

Tags: flutter

I created my own plugin for flutter and everything works on example plugin. But when I integrate it to real project, seems that my plugin get conflicted with other package, in this case is flutter local notification.
I just follow the manual from flutter for creating plugin, seems I need to edit something that not stated on the manual. Please let me know if anyone has experience about it.

Here the error : [image]

Answer (score 0):

This is conflict version between `firebase_admod` and `audioplayers` have same `_channel` variable. This conflict fixed in `audioplayers` version 0.7.8.
So upgrade `audioplayers` to version [0.7.8](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/audioplayers#-changelog-tab-) will resolve this bug